# jquery $.ajax custom http headers issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, header

I'm querying a REST webservice which uses custom http headers for authentication.

If I perform a POST without the headers I'm getting the expected error, but when I add the headers I get a 404 error instead of what I actually need.

This is my code

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://server.com/service',
  beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('CUSTOM-HEADER-KEY', 'CUSTOM-HEADER-VALUE') },
  success: function(data) {    
    alert('success.');
  }
});
```

Here's the firebug headers output:

> **OPTIONS** /service HTTP/1.1
>   Host: server.com
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Origin: null
>   Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
>   **Access-Control-Request-Headers: custom-header-key**
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Cache-Control: no-cache

and the smae headers when performing the post with poster, which returns desired result.

> **POST** /service HTTP/1.1
>   Host: server.com
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   **CUSTOM-HEADER-KEY: CUSTOM-HEADER-VALUE**
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Content-Length: 0

The difference is pretty obvious, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong in the jquery code.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Are you sending this `POST` request across servers?

Comment: Blender is on the right track. This is most likely a sandbox violation. Either access the service VIA jsonp or use your server as a proxy to the service.

Comment: "and the smae headers when performing the post with poster".. what is "POSTER" ?

Answer (score 5):

In a cross domain request if the header is not allowed by the service browser will simply remove it

At first browser browser will make an OPTION call to check for the allowed (Origin, Headers, Methods)

In your service configuration you have to allow the header in order to be able to send it to server using

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: YOUR_HEADER_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a Cross domain request. So you cannot solve it from browser side. You might need a Server Side Proxy to perform POST to a different domain.

Answer (score 2):

Any custom headers on cross domain calls triggers a pre-flight request which is an OPTIONS call. You need to either bypass security check for OPTIONS calls or handle the requests separately since the custom headers are not passed with the OPTIONS request. Also there is no harm in allowing pre-flight request since no actual data is passed back to the browser with that call. Basically the browser asks to the server if it is allowed to make that call before actually making it. You might need to check your Access-Control headers too. All these changes are on the server side btw so you need to have full control over the webservice.

Comment: Even understanding that sending customer headers on OPTIONS makes no sense from a CORS perspective...Do you know if theres a hack or workaround to add customer headers on OPTIONS request?

Comment: I said your custom headers are NOT sent with the OPTIONS request. It is basically a simple request asking if it is allowed to do POST, PUT etc on this path. And no, there is no workaround for adding any custom headers to OPTIONS calls, browsers do not allow allow this as a security measure. You can always use JSONP to go around CORS limitations but you will have to use query params to pass any data to the server as it is just a < script > GET

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not help but I think you can add the headers in the data option:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: put the results of your header request here,
  url: 'http://server.com/service',
  beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('CUSTOM-HEADER-KEY', 'CUSTOM-HEADER-VALUE') },
  success: function(data) {    
    alert('success.');
  }
});
```