# Add headers to all non-jQuery AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I know I can add headers to all jQuery AJAX requests, as explained here:
[How can I add a custom HTTP header to ajax request with js or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686827/how-can-i-add-a-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-js-or-jquery)

And here:
[Add custom http header to all jQuery AJAX Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356374/add-custom-http-header-to-all-jquery-ajax-requests)

I have a lot of code that was written without jQuery and am wondering if there is a way to add headers automatically to **all** non-jQuery ajax requests on a server, without needing to edit/modify each request code individually with something like `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Header-name", "Header-value");`