# How could I ask browser to send back a header field from server side?

Tags: http

Now I am working on a project in which I send X-Request-Id header to browser client. And now I want browser client side send this field back to my server side.
How could I implement this?

As now, I know If-Modified-Since, Cookie will be sent back to server side automatically. Does http has a way to define custom field which follows this rule?

P.S. I do not mean keep this field when a page has been refreshed or jump to another page. I use ajax request to get data from server side, my project is a SPA. The purpose of mine is to log a user's action with one unique dentifying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding http request header to a a href link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835783/adding-http-request-header-to-a-a-href-link)

Comment: I am using ajax request. I do not think this is a solution.

Comment: In that case I would edit your question to narrow down your situation, this will help you get better answers!

Answer (score 0):

You could POST data back to an endpoint on your server. You could use form submission or AJAX depending on what you are after. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: In fact, I want client side send this field back to server automaticlly everytime a new ajax request sent. And a way I can think up is add it to my ajax request headers, but lots of code will be changed if this way.

Comment: You should probably elaborate on your original question. This might possibly help you achieve what you are after ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356374/add-custom-http-header-to-all-jquery-ajax-requests

Comment: Thanks you @Ryan, this answer gives me some idea.